# SBS2011 Standard Shares not showing up to date shared files for Server 2008 on same network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, windows-sbs-2011

I have a SBS2011 Standard server with a number of files shares in place. On my Server 2008 R2 database server, I am connecting to \SBS2011-Server\IT\Installers\SomeFolder. I can see two files in that folder, but browsing the same folder locally on the SBS2011 server (and also browsing it from another client machine running Windows 7 Pro) I can see the correct number of files (8).

These files have the same permissions as the folder that they reside in, they're not hidden or anything like that.

I've tried to map the UNC path on the Server 2008 server but that doesn't change anything either.

Is there some kind of weird caching going on, and if so is there a way to disable it?

Both machines are on the same sub-net (.x.1 and .x.2 respectively) and are actually two virtual machines on the same physical server. Host server is running XenServer with just the two virtual machines on it.

I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't show for the second Server 2008 server, but does for my client? I am logged in as two different users (logged in as a local admin on the server, and as a domain-joined user on the Win7 box), but I have used the network administrator's credentials to access the network resource from the Server 2008 machine, and they both have the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be testing this using the same domain user account from both computers, not different user accounts. Using different user accounts makes the user account a variable in your test, when it should be a control/constant.

That being said, because you are using different user accounts to test this from each computer, ABE comes to mind.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710(v=ws.10).aspx